# Converting JS String to JSON object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to construct a JS on the fly for a remote validator function using the validation plugin. but for some reason, it's not converting the JS as an object and is treating it as a string and embedding double quotes.

Ex:

The PHP code I have is:

```
$remoteUrl = '/test/checkusername';
$remoteValidatorJs = "{url: '". $remoteUrl . "',
                      type: 'post',
                      async:false,
                      dataType: 'html',
                      beforeSend: function(){
                         alert('Validating Form Field');
                       },
                       complete: function(){
                         alert('Completed Validation of Form Field');
                       },
                      dataFilter: function(html) {
                          return html;
                      }
                      }";
$validation[ 'rules' ][ 'Name' ][ 'remote' ] = $remoteValidatorJs;
```

How do I frame or convert the JS in `$remoteValidatorJs` variable so, it eventually looks like the content in the following "remote" section, when the array is printed:

```
$("#testForm").validate( {
    "rules":{
        "Name":{
            "remote":{
                url: '/test/checkusername',
                type: 'post',
                async:false,
                dataType: 'html',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    alert('Validating Form Field');                     
                },complete: function(){
                    alert('Completed Validation of Form Field');                      
                },
                dataFilter: function(html) {
                    return html;                     
                }
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you have quotes at the beginning of the variable? `$remoteValidatorJs = "` - this will make the entire variable a string

Comment: That is PHP syntax to store a string in a variable

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'json object' (other than the object which handles translating between string<->native). There's json strings, which can be converted back to native objects/arrays.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a subset of javascript, your example isn't valid JSON as it's a javascript string.

The only way to evaluate it would be to use Function or eval

But without knowing what you're trying to solve I doubt evaling a string is the solution.

Using a string containing a javascript object literal with functions, the following would work. PS I haven't used your whole string :)

```
var remoteUrl = "http://something.com";
var evalString =
  [
    '{url:"' + remoteUrl + '",',
    'type:"post",',
    'async:false}'
  ].join('')
evalString #// => "{url:"http://something.com",type:"post",async:false}"
var x= new Function("return " + evalString + ";")()
#// => Object
  async: false
  type: "post"
  url: "http://something.com"
```

Comment: What would be a valid way to construct the object then?